# How to retrieve a speicific element value from an xml?

Tags: xml, xmlnode

```
<ROOT>
 <ECERT O_CRP="10" O_ORD="234567" O_CUS="34567" C_ORD_TYP="cg" O_GFCT="864695"  O_GFCT_CARD="1234567891234567890" *A_GFCT_RFD*="0.0000" D_ORD_PLC="2013-03-27 01:23:05:000" C_ORD_CAT="G" O_FNR_TEAM_MBR_VDR_ID="10000" O_FNR_CMPN_VDR_ID="20000" /> 
 <ECERT O_CRP="10" O_ORD="234568" O_CUS="34568" C_ORD_TYP="CG" O_GFCT="864696" O_GFCT_CARD="1234567891234567891" *A_GFCT_RFD*="0.0000" D_ORD_PLC="2013-03-27 01:31:31:000" C_ORD_CAT="G" O_FNR_TEAM_MBR_VDR_ID="10001" O_FNR_CMPN_VDR_ID="20001" /> 
</ROOT>
```

My xml will be like this, which I get from a data table, now i need to read "A_GFCT_RFD" from this xml to a decimal variable. I tried with Xelement, but it returned null.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is your XML looks like? and which platform do you use to parse it?

Comment: Will you be using Java?

Answer (score 0):

The asterisks (`*`) in your attribute name (`*A_GFCT_RFD*`) might be part of the problem.  Asterisk works as a wild card character in XPath expressions.  The [Xpath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-full-text-10/) suggests that you can use backslash (`\`) to escape the asterisk.

**Update**

In other words, try an XPath expression that looks like `/ROOT/ECERT@\*A_GFCT_RFD\*`.